# Use earlier row values of same pandas column to calculate the next value

Tags: python, pandas, excel, loops

I have the following data in a pandas dataframe.

| Particulars | Additions | Substraction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Add | 129 | 000 |
| Subs | 000 | 032 |
| Add | 788 | 000 |
| Subs | 000 | 402 |
| Add | 342 | 000 |
| Subs | 000 | 200 |
| Add | 553 | 000 |
| Subs | 000 | 189 |

I want it to look like this:

| Particulars | Addition | Substraction | Calculated Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Add | 129 | 000 | 129 |
| Subs | 000 | 032 | 000 |
| Add | 388 | 000 | 388 |
| Subs | 000 | 102 | 000 |
| Add | 442 | 000 | 406 |
| Subs | 000 | 200 | 000 |
| Add | 853 | 000 | 000 |
| Subs | 000 | 589 | 000 |

Rationale for Calculated Value

- Total Additions = 1812
- Total Substractions = 923

So for each row value I want it to do this:
Minimum Value of either

1. Addition value of that row, or,
2. Total Substractions - cumsum(Calculated Values up to that cell)

In an excel way it can be denoted as, assuming Addition is column B, Substraction is C and Calculated Value is D:

| Calculated Value |
| --- |
| MIN(B1, sum($C$1:$C$10) - sum($D$1:D1) |
| MIN(B2, sum($C$2:$C$10) - sum($D$1:D2) |
| MIN(B3, sum($C$2:$C$10) - sum($D$1:D3) |
| MIN(B4, sum($C$2:$C$10) - sum($D$1:D4) |
| MIN(B5, sum($C$2:$C$10) - sum($D$1:D5) |

So simply I wish to replicate the above excel in pandas column D.
However we observe that formula itself is dependent on above values of column D.

I have tried to do the same but producing multiple columns for each element of formula, but basically I am unable to identify the correct dependency to fetch values from above cells.

*To replicate dataframe from dict:*

```py
pd.DataFrame({'Particulars': {0: 'Add', 1: 'Subs', 2: 'Add', 3: 'Subs', 4: 'Add', 5: 'Subs', 6: 'Add', 7: 'Subs'},
              'Addition': {0: 129, 1: 0, 2: 388, 3: 0, 4: 442, 5: 0, 6: 853, 7: 0},
              'Substraction': {0: 0, 1: 32, 2: 0, 3: 102, 4: 0, 5: 200, 6: 0, 7: 589},
              'Expected': {0: 129, 1: 0, 2: 388, 3: 0, 4: 406, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 0}})
```

Comment: Are the values always increasing?

Comment: No it can be in any logic

Answer (score 0):

Since the calculated value of next row depends on the value of previous row there is not a direct way to use vectorized methods but you can define a function to replicate the excel formula and optionally compile it with `@njit` decorator to achive super fast C like speeds.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def func(A, S):
    cs, total = 0, sum(S)

    for a in A:
        r = min(a, total - cs)
        yield r
        cs += r


df['Calculated Value'] = [*func(df['Addition'].values, df['Subtraction'].values)]
```

---

```
  Particulars  Addition  Subtraction  Calculated Value
0         Add       129            0               129
1        Subs         0           32                 0
2         Add       388            0               388
3        Subs         0          102                 0
4         Add       442            0               406
5        Subs         0          200                 0
6         Add       853            0                 0
7        Subs         0          589                 0
```